# How to check if matched text in web element is partially enclosed in <a> tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have the following:

```
This is my text string and this next <a href='https//somelink.org/'>part</a> is only partially enclosed in a tags.
```

In the above string i have to search for "next part" not only "part" so once i find the "next part" I need to check if there is any a tag present in the matched text (sometimes there is not an  tag) - how can I do that?

Additional to my main question I can't make my xpath to work to find "next part" in the elements.

I tried this:

```
//*[contains(text(),"next part")]
```

But it doesn't find anything probably because I have spaces in there - how do I overcome this?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Try to break down the text match like this... //*[contains(text(),"next") and contains(text(),"part") ]

Comment: Can you clarify what is your expected output if a tag is present around "part" and what it's not?

Comment: @JackFleeting I would like to get True/False and the web element itself returned with it.

Comment: So to confirm: if there is no `<a>` tag in the element, you want `False`; otherwise, you want `<a href='https//somelink.org/'>part</a>`?

Comment: To match that use: `//*[contains(.,"next part")]` - but it will match the first thing (html) if you let it so maybe narrow down the * part.

Comment: @JackFleeting Yeah

Comment: @pguardiario thanks that did select the element that contains only "next part"- now to the next problem. Check if that "part" has <a> tags

Comment: @masky007 - it can't really be solved with xpath but I think I can come close with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume this html:

```
<p>This is my text string and this next <a href='https//somelink.org/'>part</a> is only partially enclosed in a tags.</p>
```

We can select with selenium:

```
p = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[contains(.,"next part")]')
```

And we can determine if it's partly in an a tag with regex (Tony the Pony notwithstanding):

```
html = p.get_attribute('innerHTML')
partly_in_a = 'next part' in re.sub(r'</?a.*?>', '', html) and 'next part' not in html
```

There's no pure xpath 1.0 solution for this, and it's a mistake in general to depend on xpath for stuff like this.

Comment: That's it, works perfectly, thank you kind internet stranger.
To the point and precise- appreciated!

Out of curiosity, is there a way to solve this with xpath 2.0?

Comment: It might be possible with xpath 2, but I don't see the point. Xpath is mostly an ancient relic from when we used to use xml for things that we now use json for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a nested XPath selector for this.

```
//*[contains(text(), 'next') and a[contains(text(), 'part')]]
```

This will query on any element that contains text `next`, then also check that the element contains nested `a` element with text `part`.

To determine whether or not there actually IS a nested `a` tag, you will need to write a method for this that checks against two different XPaths. There is no easy way around this, other than to evaluate the elements and see what's there.

```
public bool DoesElementHaveNestedTag()
{
    // check for presence of locator with nested tag
    // if driver.findElements returns > 0, then nested tag locator exists
    if (driver.findElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'next') and a[contains(text(), 'part')]]")).Count > 0) return true
    else return false
}
```

You can change this method to fit your needs, but the idea is the same. There is no way to know if a WebElement has a nested tag or not, unless you try to find the WebElement using two XPaths -- one that checks for the tag, and one that does not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I appreciate your help. Though that xpath did not work for me (not sure why)